# umbraco lucene syntax for not

Tags: syntax, lucene, umbraco

I am trying to write a lucene query to retrieve some pages in my website so I have the following:

```
string.Format("nodeName: ({0})^7 bodyText: ({0})^6", _searchTerm)
```

which means it will search for content that either has the `nodeName` or the `bodyText` that includes the `_searchTerm` variable

where I am struggling is that I also want it to not include any results that have a `hideInNav` flag set to `1` so I tried:

```
string.Format("nodeName: ({0})^7 bodyText: ({0})^6 +hideInNav: NOT(1)", _searchTerm)
```

However this is throwing up the following error:

```
Encountered " <NOT> "NOT "" at line 1, column 140.
Was expecting one of:
   "(" ...
   "*" ...
   <QUOTED> ...
   <TERM> ...
   <PREFIXTERM> ...
   <WILDTERM> ...
   "[" ...
   "{" ...
   <NUMBER> ...
```

As far as I can tell the query does have a `(` after the NOT so I'm stumped as to where this is being expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
string.Format("nodeName: ({0})^7 bodyText: ({0})^6 !hideInNav: (1)", _searchTerm)
```

The exclamation mark can also be changed to NOT:

```
string.Format("nodeName: ({0})^7 bodyText: ({0})^6 NOT hideInNav: (1)", _searchTerm)
```

See [this page](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/queryparsersyntax.html) for an overview of the Lucene Query syntax (it's not the current version but I doubt it changed a lot)

Edit: maybe reversing you hideInNave statement will fix it:

string.Format("nodeName: ({0})^7 bodyText: ({0})^6 +hideInNav: (0)", _searchTerm)  to check if it is zero or check if it is zero.

You might want to also download [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to check the content of your index and see how values are saved.

Comment: hi, I saw that page and it didn't really help that much. I think I am unable to do what I am trying as "The NOT operator cannot be used with just one term"

Comment: Did you try the query?
You have more terms in your query so in your case the one term NOT is not applicable.

Comment: Hi, I did try the query but unfortunately it returned no results

Comment: I notice you use parentheses aroudn the search term, that is used for grouping. What happens if you create a hardcoded query like this:

nodeName: "testname"^6 bodyText: "testText"^7 NOT hideInNav: "1"

To make sure the issue is not in your formatting.

Comment: Hi, thanks I also tried that but the problem with using 0 is that this is sometimes null as Umbraco doesn't allow me to set a default value (which is why I had to try using the not statement).  I also tried without the parenthesis but it also didn't work.

Comment: As it turns out the only reason no result were being returned is because the Umbraco Lucene search needs to have a fuzziness of 0.8 set otherwise it's result set is very low - hence the no results being returned.  Thanks for your help